# timestamp_micros function in athena

Tags: amazon-athena

I have a bigquery like this

```
TIMESTAMP_MICROS(timestamp)
```

I tried this query in Athena

```
date_format(from_unixtime(timestamp / 1000), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

but the result is

51885-10-16 19:24:27 for the value 1575190265067000

how can I get the correct result in Athena?

Comment: are you asking how to get the correct result in AWS Athena?

Comment: Yes exactly, I want the correct result in athena

Comment: I got the answer, it should be divided by 1000000 instead of 1000, thanks